# Get the object that an object is assigned to, how?

Tags: java

I dont know how to really ask this.
But like...

```
Student stud1 = new Student("Shady");
Student stud2 = new Student("Nick");
Student stud3 = new Student("Name");

stud2.addBook(new Book(Book.BOOK_MISERABLES, 3););
```

Now if we assume we have the following variable in the Book class:

```
private Student owner;
```

And now the question, inside the constructor of "Book" -> Is it possible to get the "stud2" object it's being called to? Without adding an additional parameter to the constructor? If so, how? I think it's possible... So it will be something like this:

```
private Student owner;

public Book(int bookNum, int weeks){
    this.owner = this.GET_THE_TARGET_THIS_IS_CALLED_ON;
    this.bookNumber = bookNum;
    this.time = weeks;
}
```

Comment: No, it isn't possible. And, I see no reason why you should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're asking is not directly possible. You will need to either

- Pass a reference to the `Student` instance to your `Book` constructor

or

- Use a setter inside the `Book` class to set the value of the `owner` field to your `Student` instance.

The latter would be a method that looks like this:

```
public void setOwner(Student owner) {
  this.owner = owner;
}
```

Additionally, you may want to modify your `Student.addBook` method to call this setter, like this:

```
book.setOwner(this);
```

---

As you mentioned in your comment, you can traverse the stack using `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` However, you'll be unable to obtain an object reference using that technique. You can obtain the `class` or `method` name but the uses for that are limited unless you intend to construct a new instance. That's all highly unorthodox and not at all appropriate for this situation.

Comment: I guess it's impossible, I thought it's something like StackTrace. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Shady I've added information on traversing the stack and why it is neither useful or appropriate in this case. If this answers your question, please consider accepting it as the answer.